# How to estimate gas at contract creation/deployment to private ethereum blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, remix, gas-estimate

**What I have done**
a) When I use `web3.eth.estimateGas` to estimate the cost of a contract creation constructor with no parameters, the estimate is correct.

b) If the contract is already  deployed then estimating the gas cost of a contract function with parameters, it works fine. (`contract.myMethod.estimateGas()` using the web3 api )

**Issue**
a) When I estimate gas in a contract on contract creation time (`contractObject.new`) with a parameterized constructor then it gives an incorrect estimation of gas cost. (`web3.eth.estimateGas` of web3 api)

**What I want**
a) When I estimate gas with multiple parameter constructor of contract then it should estimate correct gas.
 (`contractObject.new` for calling constructor)

b) Browser-soldity gives right gas estimation of contract with parametrized constructor --> before contract create/deploy (like transaction cost or execution cost, how can I use their algorithm with web3 api to estimate gas correct way?)

Comment: How are you using `.estimateGas()`? With `.getData()`?

Comment: Matthew Schmidt i am using estimateGas() function with method of contract to estimatote gas. i am not using any .getData() method.
for example:- 
contractInstance.myMethod.estimateGas method give right result. but i want to estimate contractInstance.new for constructor calling with parametrized . 
when i estimateGas of contractInstance.new.estimateGas , it give's error, that method does not exist. how to fix it

Answer (score 18):

Try using `.getData()`.

`.getData()` returns the encoded parameters of a function in order to send the transaction manually. You can then stick this in `web3.eth.estimateGas()` (the one on `web3.eth`, not on a given method.) to simulate sending the transaction.

Here's an untested example, but hopefully it can help you on your way:

```
var contractData = contractObject.new.getData(someparam, another, {data: contractBytecode});
var estimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({data: contractData})
```

#### References:

[web3.eth.estimateGas()](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethestimategas)

[An example of using .getData()](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract) (It's the fourth option.)

Comment: What does 'contractCode' refer to in your first example line?

Comment: Whoops! Should have been a bit clearer. That's the contract bytecode--what you get from `solc --bin` I'll edit my answer.

Comment: These method seems to not work with web3 version 1.0 since there is no `getData()`? Edit: Found [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26234/getdata-is-not-working) which says to use `encodeABI()` instead of `getData()`.

Answer (score 3):

When working with web3.js version 1.2.x, there is not .getData method.
The solution I found was to estimate of gas of the .deploy() method, which effectively returns the cost of contract creation.

The sequence of operations is:

```
let contractJSON = // JSON compiled contract
const contractABI = contractJSON.abi;
const bytecode = contractJSON.bytecode;
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI);
let options = {
    arguments: [ arg1, arg2,... ],
    data: bytecode
}
const estimatedGas = await contract.deploy(options).estimateGas();
```

Answer (score 1):

With web3js, it's pretty easy. First you need to create your contract. After creation, you'll have contractABI and the contract address like this:

```
let contractABI = [ { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "verify", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "address", "value": "0x" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "document", "type": "bytes32" } ], "name": "sign", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "type": "function" } ]
let contractAddress = '0xaEC9eCDAFAf2404F824B4b7087e9E4F90C77D082'
```

With these informations, just create the contract proxy **contractInstance** and estimate a tx on a **sign** method:

```
const web3conn = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
const contract = web3conn.eth.contract(contractABI)
const contractInstance = contract.at(contractAddress)
let estimatedGas = contractInstance.sign.estimateGas('arg of my function', { from: '0xAddress' })
```

The proxy is a special object (use a console.log to see all methods) to facilitate contract usage. If you have a **sign** method, you can create a Tx to sign:

```
let txHash = contractInstance.sign(param, { from: config.ethereum.identity, gas: estimatedGas })
```

if you use wan't to call a function (without transaction):

```
contractInstance.sign.call(param)
```

Comment: Question is about gas estimate on contact creation.

Answer (score 0):

Web3 allows this:

```js
const MyContract = artifacts.require('MyContract');

...

const gas = await MyContract.new.estimateGas(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI);
const bytecodeWithEncodedParameters = contract
    .deploy({
        data: contractByteCode,
        arguments: [?, ?, ?],
    })
    .encodeABI();

const estimateGas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
    data: bytecodeWithEncodedParameters,
});
```

Try like this for new contract deployment. It works for me.