# GAS is the fuel of Ethereum network?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development, gas-price, gas-limit

I want to know something about GAS...can you please explain...

1. What is the relationship between Gas and Wei / Ether? Can you please give an example of how much the execution of a contract will cost?
2. What is maximum GAS amount for a contract. I want to mean is there any restriction for the the amount of GAS in a contract?
3. How much will the execution of a contract cost in real world (just estimation)?

Comment: Hi Tamim, these are all good questions but need to be answered separately.  Can you break them apart and post them one by one?

Answer (score 2):

1. Gas is paid for by ether and used to compensate the network for verifying your transaction. Wei is a multiple ETH.
2. The gas spent on a transaction is `(gas used * gas price)`. The maximum gas amount for a **transaction** is the maximum amount of gas which a transaction is allowed to use. If more gas is required, the transaction will fail.
3. It depends on the contract. You can check by using [web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11053/how-to-estimate-gas-at-contract-creation-deployment-to-private-ethereum-blockcha).

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, please mark it as the answer: ✔️