# getData() is not working

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, javascript, nodejs

I want to call a function of the contract, something like this -

```
module.exports.transfer = function(to,value,){ 
   return token.methods.transfer.getData(to, value);
}
```

But I am facing the error

> token.methods.transfer.getData is not a function

How do i resolve it , is getData() deprecated or their is any other way to get the data of function with desired arguments ?

web3 version - 1.0 beta

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

For web3 1.0 beta you should use [`encodeABI`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-encodeabi), from the documentation:

```
myContract.methods.myMethod(123).encodeABI();
```

Answer (score 0):

for web3 1.2.1(new release) you should use it like:

```
    contract_interfact.methods.methodName().call({from:"address"},(err,res) => {
       ...
})


    contract_interfact.methods.methodName(arguments).send({from:"address"},(err,res) => {
        ...
})
```