# How can I estimate gas on a transaction with custom data?

Tags: gas-estimate

How can I estimate the gas I need for a string which may be quite long?

[I've found an example here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11053/how-to-estimate-gas-at-contract-creation-deployment-to-private-ethereum-blockcha/11114#11114), but in this estimate, it doesn't include any custom data.

In my app I would like to save a string on-chain, though the [estimateGas](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethestimategas)'s `data` property appears to require the bytecode for the contract.

How would I go about dealing with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `contract.method.estimateGas(...)` instead of `contract.method.sendTransaction(...)`.

`web3.eth.estimateGas` also works fine, but you'll have to first compute the `data` field. (It should be whatever data you'd send in the transaction, which is the contract bytecode only for contract deployment. For most transactions, it's the encoded function arguments.) The `estimateGas` function that hangs off of your contract's functions does the right encoding for you.

Comment: That's great, `contract.method.estimateGas(arg, object)` works great, thanks! I guess with `web3.eth.estimateGas`, you need the contract's bytecode which you may not have access to, unless you can get that dynamically? (sorry newb)

Comment: The contract's bytecode is publicly available, but you would have to manually construct the `data` field, which is much easier if you know the contract's **ABI**, which describes the public methods and their arguments.

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you confirm if estimateGas an estimate of gas required, or is it a total of (gas * gas price)?

Comment: Just the amount of gas required.