# Truffle and Ganache - do I need to set the same gas-price and gas-limit in both of them?

Tags: truffle, gas-limit, ganache, gas-price

Or can I set different values?

If I can set different values, then how will they be used in the system (i.e., what gas-price and gas-limit will apply in every transaction that I execute)?

Here is my present configuration (using the same values for Truffle and for Ganache):

**Truffle:**

```
module.exports = {
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 8545,
            network_id: "*",
            gasPrice: 100000000000,
            gas: 6721975 // gas limit
        }
    }
};
```

**Ganache:**

```
--port=8545
--gasPrice=100000000000
--gasLimit=6721975
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR: Yes you can use the same value.**

Here is why:

**Ganache**

[Ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) is a local test Blockchain.

- `-l` or `--gasLimit` is the *block gas limit* (total amount in *gas unit* that can fit in a block). Let's say for example your block gasLimit is 1000000, you would be able to fit only 10 transactions of 100000 gas units each.
- `-g` or `--gasPrice` is the default price per gas unit *in wei*. If a transaction doesn't set the gasPrice, this default price is used to calculate the gas fee [`fee=gasUsed*gasPrice`].

**Truffle**

In truffle configuration, this is different:

```
module.exports = {
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 8545,
            network_id: "*",
            gasPrice: 100000000000,
            gas: 6721975 // gas limit
        }
    }
};
```

- `gasPrice` represents the price you willing to pay per gas unit to deploy the contracts you have under this Truffle project. Using Ganache, you can set the almost any value I would imagine.
- `gas` is the maximum number of gas unit the EVM can use to process the contract deployment transaction. If it's too low, the transaction would fail, if it's too high, the excess will be refunded but if the effective gas used is higher than the block gas limit, the transaction will fail.

**Metamask**

When a user interacts with the contract deployed above (using Truffle), he can choose the gasLimit and the gasPrice:

- `gasLimit`: is the maximum number of gas unit the EVM can use to process the transaction. It is recommended to use the function [estimateGas](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas) to setup the limit (that's what Metamask is doing by default).
- `gasPrice`: represents the price you willing to pay per gas unit. It is recommended to check [EthGasStation](https://ethgasstation.info/) to estimate how long it would take to get a transaction mined. Of course higher is the price, higher is the chance to be mined quickly.

*Same concept here as Truffle except it is not only for contract deployment and migration script but any kind of transaction (transfer, contract methods, contract deployment)*

**Summary**

```
gas fee estimation (wei) = gasEstimation (or gasLimit) * gasPrice

gas fee effective (wei) = gasUsed * gasPrice

gasEstimation >= gasUsed

gasUsed <= blockGasLimit
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer!!! I know that I can use the same values, because I AM using the same values (in both Truffle and Ganache, as specified in the question). My specific question was actually: "If I can set different values, then how will they be used in the system (i.e., what gas-price and gas-limit will apply in every transaction that I execute)?". Would you be able to refer to this question as well? Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry if my answer is ambiguous. As mentioned, Truffle `gasLimit` and `gasPrice` aren't the same thing as Ganache `gas` and `gasPrice`. In Ganache, `gas` refers to the block size limit and `gasPrice` to the default gasPrice if a transaction is sent without gasPrice. While Truffle `gasLimit*gasPrice` is a maximum amount of gas fee you are willing to pay for the contract deployment only! Every transaction require a `gasLimit` which is often hidden because of the use of `estimateGas` function and gasPrice can be empty and if so will be set to Ganache gasPrice (default).

Comment: "Truffle `gasLimit*gasPrice` is a maximum amount of gas fee you are willing to pay for the contract deployment only" - are you certain about this? In Truffle tests, we typically never specify gas price nor gas limit. Does Truffle leave them empty when sending the transaction to Ganache? Your statement above implies that it does, except for the case of `contract.deploy`. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not saying that Truffle sends the transaction without gasLimit and/or gasPrice. If empty, I believe Truffle defaults the value - for gasLimit with an estimate - [see this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11114/4108) - for gasPrice with [`web3.eth.getGasPrice`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getgasprice) which should be equals to Ganache gas block limit `--gasLimit` but that might not be true all the time depends of the ganache block history > "gas price is determined by the last few blocks median gas price"

Comment: But you are saying that it doesn't use the values provided in `truffle-config.js`... am I right?

Comment: No no I said **If empty**... Truffle uses the values provided by `truffle-config.js`. But these values are optional. I was just explaining how Truffle calculates the default value if it's not specified in the config file...